# Whenever I collapse the table border in html I cant edit border color

Tags: html, css

Hi Im writing some html code in which I have too make to tables to contrast.In one table I've made the border-collapse property as separate and in the other I've made it collapse. The issue is in the other table since I override it to collapse the border for some reason I am not able to change the border color using the color property. Here is some code for review

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Living vs Non living</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body{background-color:RGB(255,251,214)}
    table,th,td{border:1px solid red}
    table{border-collapse:separate;border-spacing:20px}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <caption><h3>Livings things and non-living things</h3></caption>
    <tr>
        <th style = background-color:red;color:white>Living things</th>
        <th style = background-color:red;color:white>Non Living things</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Consists of cell</td>
        <td>No cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Needs food for energy</td>
        <td>Needs no food</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Shows growth and movement</td>
        <td>No growth and movement</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:blue;color:white">
    <caption><h3>Livings things and non-living things</h3></caption>
    <tr>
        <th style = background-color:cyan>Living things</th>
        <th style = background-color:cyan>Non Living things</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Consists of cell</td>
        <td>No cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Needs food for energy</td>
        <td>Needs no food</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Shows growth and movement</td>
        <td>No growth and movement</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for taking your time and reading my issues

Comment: sorry posted the wrong code the second table style is: <table style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:blue;border-collapse:collapse">

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it worked all I needed to do was edit the td and th individually as well as done above in the heading.This was put I think to like make it easier to edit ever element in the table